# Search option for finding posts by mods

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderators, search

This is kind of an edge case, but can we add an advanced super ninja search option for matching posts owned by a ♦? I keep running into the case where I remember that a meta post was posted by a dev, but can't actually remember which one, and can't get the search terms close enough to find it. Something like `user:mod` or `bymod:1` would be helpful

Comment: Just change your focus to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A146126

Comment: Would you also be interested in it returning results for former mods?

Comment: @squillman I guess showing posts by people that were mods when they wrote them would be potentially useful, but I'm sure that's much more complicated; just current diamonds would be fine

Comment: Declining this...that's too much of an edge case to add to the supported syntax list.

Comment: @Nick My use case is more like the ["Dev Tracker"](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/devtracker)s seen in game-specific forums hosted by developers of the game. I wanted to see how the moderators have been using meta in general, if there was such a search flag supported. So in my case, I'm interested in finding posts by current and former mods that were made only when the poster was a mod.

Answer (score 5):

This is too specialized a requirement for the UI. Reach for the API. There's a query to return the [list of moderators](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/moderators), and from there you can return their [questions](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-questions) and [answers](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-answers).

Here's a crudely-crafter script that shows the list of posts by moderators. Pass it two arguments: the site name, and further parameters to restrict the post queries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json, re, sys, urllib
(site, params) = (sys.argv[i] for i in (1,2))

def get(tail):
    stream = urllib.urlopen("http://api." + site + "/1.1/" + tail)
    data = json.load(stream)
    stream.close()
    return data
def quote_for_markdown(raw):
    return re.sub("[][*<>\\`]", "\g<0>", raw)

mods = [m["user_id"] for m in get("users/moderators")["users"]]
base = "users/" + ";".join(map(str, mods)) + "/"
questions = get(base + "questions?" + params)
answers = get(base + "answers?" + params)
posts = ([(q["question_id"], q["title"]) for q in questions["questions"]] +
         [(q["answer_id"], q["title"]) for q in answers["answers"]])
posts.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
for (id, title) in posts:
    print "[%s](http://%s/q/%d)" % (quote_for_markdown(title), site, id)
```

Example: yesterday's posts from moderators on Meta.SO:

```
python get_moderator_posts meta.stackoverflow.com "answers?fromdate=1309305600&todate=1309392000"
```

Answer (score 3):

There aren't that many ♦ moderators; couldn't you just search for each individually?

Comment: There are 14 here, and it's more often the case that I'm looking for a dev post; there's like 20 of them

Comment: There are 11 devs/employees on Meta. Or at least, 11 who have diamonds.

Comment: @mmyers Well, due to my spectacular laziness, that's enough for me to want a search option

Comment: @Michael +1 simply for that comment alone